# Convert property to django model field

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to create virtual model field in django?

For example I have

```
class A(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @apply
    def virtual_field():
       def fget(self):
           return self.field1 + '/' + self.field2
       def fset(self, value):
           self.field_1, self_field_2 = value.split('/')
           return True
       return property(**locals())
```

Now, if I will run:

```
a = A()
a.virtual_field = '5/5'
a.save()
```

it will work fine.

But I have a dump, where I have model A with virtual_field value - on serialization I've got an error "A object has no virtual_field"... How I can cheat serializer and tell it, that virtual_field exists?

Comment: standard django serializer which called on test, loaddata.

Comment: Just wonder why do you want to serialize a virtual field. It could get value from `field1` and `field2` already.

Comment: Because I have lots of legacy fixtures for example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to load from legacy fixture, you could build some intermediate model/table, convert file or customize dumpdata command. Fool dumpdata is possible, as following, but hmm...

```
class VirtualField(object):
    rel = None

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        self.attname = self.name = name
        # cls._meta.add_virtual_field(self)
        get_field = cls._meta.get_field
        cls._meta.get_field = lambda name, many_to_many=True: self if name == self.name else get_field(name, many_to_many)
        models.signals.pre_init.connect(self.pre_init, sender=cls) #, weak=False)
        models.signals.post_init.connect(self.post_init, sender=cls) #, weak=False)
        setattr(cls, name, self)

    def pre_init(self, signal, sender, args, kwargs, **_kwargs):
        sender._meta._field_name_cache.append(self)

    def post_init(self, signal, sender, **kwargs):
        sender._meta._field_name_cache[:] = sender._meta._field_name_cache[:-1]

    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance.field1 + '/' + instance.field2

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if instance is None:
             raise AttributeError(u"%s must be accessed via instance" % self.related.opts.object_name)
        instance.field1, instance.field2 = value.split('/')

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value

class A(models.Model):
     field1 = models.TextField()
     field2 = models.TextField()
     virtual_field = VirtualField()

# legacy.json
[{"pk": 1, "model": "so.a", "fields": {"virtual_field": "A/B"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "so.a", "fields": {"virtual_field": "199/200"}}]

$ ./manage.py loaddump legacy.json
Installed 2 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

Or you could add customized serializer to public serializers and mainly override  its `Deserializer` function to work w/ properties that you have. Mainly override to tweak two lines in `Deserializer` inside `django/core/serializers/python.py`

```
field = Model._meta.get_field(field_name)
# and
yield base.DeserializedObject(Model(**data), m2m_data)
```

Comment: That helped me better understand fixtures. Thanks.